# Is it OK to have 2 FKs on a table, which point to different tables, and one of which will only be used?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Lets assume I have 2 tables:

```
Order -< OrderItem
```

I have another table with 2 FKs:

```
Feature
 - Id
 - FkOrderId
 - FkOrderItemId
 - Text
```

UPDATE

---

This table is linked to another called FeatureReason which is common to both types of record, be they OrderFeatures or OrderItem features.

Feature -< FeatureReason

If I had 2 feature tables to account for both types of records, would this then require 2 FeatureReason tables. Same issue here with the FeatureReason table needing to have 2 FKs, each pointing to a different master table.

---

An Order can have a Feature record, as can an OrderItem. Therefore either "FkOrderId" OR FkOrderItemId would be populated. Is this fine to do?

I would also seriously think about using Views to to insert/edit and read either OrderFeatures or OrderItemFeatures.

Thoughts appreciated.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with views for the data. A CASE statement and testing for NULL will do the trick. I would only use a view if security was a particular concern where only certain users can view certain bits of the data.

Comment: you can keep multiple fk in a single table and each foreign must point a different table.

Comment: What's stored in the `text` column?  Are features unique per order-item?  I have a feeling you should probably head towards cross-ref tables, which would solve some of this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend using following structure, because if you have 2 foreign keys which either of them can be null, you can have rows with both columns being null or having value.

Added the FeatureReason table too

[image: Tables]

Comment: This would allow for n:m relationship, but this is not what the OP wants. He wants n:1. Each Order, and each OrderItem, can have 1 Feature at most.

Comment: Actually OP's table structure means one feature can have one order and one orderitem, which I dont think is what he intended to have. I think he wants to have a set of features which can be linked to Order and or OrderItems

Comment: @JanneMatikainen you are correct. Yes a number of features could be created for both Order and OrderItem tables. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, but why? What is your reasoning for collating these two distinct items in a single table?

I would suggest having two separate tables, `OrderFeatures` and `OrderItemFeatures`, and on those occasions that you need to query both, collate them with a `union` query.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have just posted an Update in response to your advice. I missed explaining that there is a detail table that hangs off this "Feature" table.

Comment: The same rule applies - the diagram by @JanneMatikainen shows this, is a better structure than your proposal, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have 2 foreign keys in one table. As long as the foreign key is mapping with the primary key on another table, it's OK

Comment: Yes it is mapping to the PK. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

By not populating FkOrderItemId or FkOrderId, will you not be violating one or other of the FK constraints?

You can populate FkOrderItemId or FkOrderId according to your needs, I'm just not sure about defining an FK where it is not mandatory to supply a FK value.

Just a thought...

Comment: Yes, they would need to be nullable.